# Can we measure the minimum blocklenght required for any coding scheme given specific values of error probability and rate of transmission?

Tags: information-theory

The *noisy-channel coding theorem* states that any error probability can be achieved as long as the transmission rate stays below the capacity of the channel. However, as we go to the more efficient codings, there's also an increase in the blocklenght needed.

So my question is: Is there a  way of precisely stating this trade-off?

Say. With the desired error probability and the desired transmission rate. Could you evaluate exactly what's the minimum blocklenght needed for the coding?

Please correct me if any of my assumptions are false.

Comment: What do you mean by 'memory'? Block (codeword) length? Or are you referring to hardware implementation aspects?

Comment: I mean blocklenght. I've edited the question.

Comment: there are no exact formulas for the (maximum) transmission rate as a function of the blocklength and error probability. However, tight approximations have been obtained recently in [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwinmYbnpebjAhWHPFAKHTsZA4kQFjAFegQIBhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.chalmers.se%2F~hegarty%2Ffinite_block.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1jlmyM1BXTqr16WvcOtpyq).

Comment: @Stelios Perhaps you should turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks! I would probably do that if I was in a position to provide a few comments on the work rather than just refer to it. However, I am not familiar with the paper and can only provide the reference, which, I think, is not really an answer. I would certainly upvote an answer elaborating a bit on what this seminal paper (or others related) states on this important topic.